# how can i add spaces generic way by passing parameter using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

is any way to create function create wanted spaces in the output, because i was keep hot coding were ever i required space `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text >`, kindly suggest a function to generate a space based on the passed parameter,please advice

Comment: if suppose i pass a parameter value as 36 then call template should provide the 36 space subsequently

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if we could see some sample XML, the output XML that you require, and the XSLT that you've attempted thus far.

Comment: @bach, quite simple my question is, but i need it in generic way, example if you need space between two strings means i can do like this way  <xsl:text>FACE</xsl:text > <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text > <xsl:text>BOOK</xsl:text >, similarly i dont want to hot code for Space,if have a template function, then i will pass parameter to the function use call template by parameter value, then based on the parameter value it should create spaces for that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking at recursive template. Something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="WriteSpaces">
   <xsl:param name="count" />
   <xsl:if test="$count &gt; 0">
     <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
     <xsl:call-template name="WriteSpaces">
       <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1" />
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Notice that invoking this would actually pollute your code even more than just putting spaces directly. For static content I would probably just use text. For dynamic content (i.e. if you want `<xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="." /><xsl:text>    </xsl:text>`) I would use concat() function as it does not limit the number of parameters - so you could code above just as `<xsl:value-of select="concat('  ', ., '   ')" />`.

Comment: <xsl:templatematch="/">          
<xsl:text>Hi</xsl:text >
<xsl:call-template name="WriteSpaces">
<xsl:with-param name="count" select= "'9'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:text>PRAVEEN</xsl:text >
</xsl:template> i am using like this but it is not working, please advice

Comment: i am expecting Hi          PRAVEEN, nine spaces between the two words

Comment: I just tried and seems to be working for me - this is what I got `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><out>Hi         PRAVEEN</out>` (there is 9 spaces - stackoverflow seems to collapse them). Can you elaborate more on what's not working? What output do you use in your xslt? How do you view the transformation result?